# Match all after "word" if exists, if "word" does not exist, match all

Tags: java, regex

I have the two following sentences:

> 1: KEYWORD this is a random sentence 
>   2: this is another random sentence

I would like to match all after KEYWORD if KEYWORD exists, and if it doesn't, I want to match all.
So the output would be:

> 1: this is a random sentence
>   2: this is another random sentence

I tried a few things that did not lead me anywhere close:

```
(?<=KEYWORD)[\s\S]+
```

This would only match everything after the keyword, but will fail to capture anything if the keyword is not present...

PS: I use java

Comment: Add a language tag. Show code. Regexes are not standalone concepts in Java. You have to show how you match them, since there are a number of options available, many of which are not what you want.

Comment: why not replace everything till `keyword`?

Comment: @rock321987. Because then you wouldn't need the sledgehammer that is regex.

Comment: Try `(?<=KEYWORD).*|^(?:(?!KEYWORD).)*$`

Comment: [You may use this regex `(?<=KEYWORD |^(?!.*KEYWORD)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/TdyA7Y/1)

Comment: @ctwheels This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Kylke already done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to ctwheel's nice working solution you may be able to use this regex that may perform faster because of no tempered greedy token that asserts a lookahead before every character.

```
(?<=KEYWORD |^(?!.*KEYWORD)).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdyA7Y/1/)

**Details:**

- `(?<=KEYWORD`: If we have `"KEYWORD "` at previous position
- `|`: OR
- `^(?!.*KEYWORD)`: We don't have `KEYWORD` anywhere in the line
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters

Comment: Thanks :) That makes a lot of sense! No idea, why I haven't thought of this when I looked for a solution...

Answer (score 3):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/WqIUOR/1)

```
(?<=KEYWORD).*|^(?:(?!KEYWORD).)*$
```

- Option 1

  - `(?<=KEYWORD)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `KEYWORD`
  - `.*` Match any character (except `\n`) any number of times
- Option 2

  - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
  - `(?:(?!KEYWORD).)*` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character except where `KEYWORD` matches
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Result:

```
this is a random sentence
this is another random sentence
```

Comment: Tempered greedy token pattern isn't really needed, I left a comment above.

Comment: @anubhava interesting, I like it you should post as another option :)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about tempered greedy token. It looks usefull in some cases.